# How get HashMap key value in Kotlin in android

Tags: android, kotlin

```
if (appPreference.getStorageInfo().isNotEmpty() && appPreference.getStorageInfo()
                    .containsKey(modelNumber)
            ) {
                val linkedHashMap = appPreference.getStorageInfo()
                containerView.apply {
                    tv_total.text = (linkedHashMap[modelNumber] as StorageData)?.total
                    tv_free.text = (linkedHashMap[modelNumber] as StorageData)?.free
                    tv_movie.text = (linkedHashMap[modelNumber] as StorageData)?.movie
                    tv_event.text = (linkedHashMap[modelNumber] as StorageData)?.event
                }

            }
```

This is my code i am able to get data linkedHashMap variable as key and value and i am trying to get  value

[image]

When i try to get value from key then i am getting below error in our code

```
                                                                                                java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.productregistraion.entities.StorageData
```

Can any one please help me how to get value base on key so that i can print data from value i have created map MutableMap<String, StorageData> but its showing that our value data in LinkedTreeMap so its not mapping StorageData please help and suggest where i am doing wrong .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering, java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.rovedashcam.newmodeule.productregistraion.entities.StorageData, indicates that you're trying to cast a LinkedTreeMap object to StorageData, which is not compatible and hence causing the exception.

This happens because when you deserialize JSON data into a LinkedHashMap, Gson (the JSON library you're using) uses LinkedTreeMap internally to represent JSON objects. When you retrieve values from the LinkedHashMap, Gson returns LinkedTreeMap objects instead of your custom StorageData objects.

To resolve this issue, you need to properly convert the LinkedTreeMap objects to your StorageData objects. You can achieve this by manually mapping the LinkedTreeMap objects to StorageData objects.

```
val linkedHashMap = appPreference.getStorageInfo()
if (linkedHashMap.isNotEmpty() && linkedHashMap.containsKey(modelNumber)) {
    val storageDataMap = linkedHashMap[modelNumber] as? LinkedTreeMap<*, *>
    if (storageDataMap != null) {
        val storageData = StorageData().apply {
            total = storageDataMap["total"] as? String ?: ""
            free = storageDataMap["free"] as? String ?: ""
            movie = storageDataMap["movie"] as? String ?: ""
            event = storageDataMap["event"] as? String ?: ""
        }

        // Now you have a valid StorageData object
        containerView.apply {
            tv_total.text = storageData.total
            tv_free.text = storageData.free
            tv_movie.text = storageData.movie
            tv_event.text = storageData.event
        }
    } else {
        // Handle case where StorageData is null or invalid
    }
} else {
    // Handle case where modelNumber is not found or linkedHashMap is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because Gson is deserializing your JSON string to a `Map<*, *>` because you haven't told it what types the map contains. When it finds what looks like a String and a JSON object (which happens to be a `StorageData`, but Gson doesn't know that), Gson deserializes your StorageData into a Map whose specific type is a Gson internal type `LinkedTreeMap`.

To tell Gson to use your `StorageData` class, you need to use `TypeToken` in your `getStorageInfo` function:

```
val storageDataMapType = object : TypeToken<Map<String, StorageData>>() {}.type
val map: Map<String, StorageData> = gson.fromJson(jsonString, storageDataMapType)
return map
```

Then you can use your map directly as Gson will have done the conversion to `StorageData` for you. Furthermore, your existing code can be simplified to the following:

```
val storageData = appPreference.getStorageInfo()?.get(modelNumber)
containerView.apply {
    tv_total.text = storageData?.total
    tv_free.text = storageData?.free
    tv_movie.text = storageData?.movie
    tv_event.text = storageData?.event
}
```